# Comparing interface variable without cast to Enum value in java

Tags: java, enums, interface, compare, comparison

Is there a specification or documentation why this comparison works?

```
static void sout(final Interface i) {
    if(i == Enum.TWO) {
        ...
    }
}

...

public enum Enum implements Interface{
    ONE, TWO, THREE
}
```

So why is there no cast or `instanceof` needed?

Comment: Yes: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.21.3

Comment: Because `i == Enum.TWO` is true. Not sure why you think this has anything to do with your `Interface`. It would get the same result if you would change the method to `sout(final Object i)`.

Comment: Let’s ask a different question - why wouldn’t it work?

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS what if `i` is a `String`?

Comment: then `i == Enum.TWO` would obviously not be true. Not sure what your point is.

Comment: @OHGODSPIDERS not only would it not be true, it wouldn't even compile. That's probably the point the object of your phobia was trying to make. It's addressed in Andy's link.

Comment: You're right. The comparison of the interface with an actual implementation got me confused. But the hint to replace `Interface` with `Object` and Andy's link made it clear.
Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you @AndyTurner! This is what i was looking for.

There's no instanceof or explicit cast needed:

> It is a compile-time error if it is impossible to convert the type of either operand to the type of the other...

At run-time this is a normal object equality equals.

Comment: Thx, but it said only after 48 hours ;)